# "PuTTY key format too new" when using ppk file for PuTTY SSH key authentication

Tags: bash, ssh, unix, putty

I wanted to connect to my Unix server using SSH keys. For that I had converted my `id_rsa` file from `./ssh` directory to a ppk file using PuTTYgen, but after loading my `.ppk` key I get this warning:

> PuTTY key format too new

[image]

If I use my default `id_rsa` file, then I get error:

> OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format)

Either way I am getting stuck. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Easy way to fix this issue, please follow the pictures.
Step1:
[image]
Step2:
[image]

Comment: After getting the same error, then doing this, I now get from Pageant "Couldn't load this key (Open SSH SSH-2 private key (old PEM format) - a rock and a hard place

Answer (score 42):

If you have a key in the new PPK version 3 format, you can use PuTTYgen to export it to the old PPK version 2 format.

I don't know what Operating System you're using **PuTTYgen/PuTTY** on, but if it's *Microsoft Windows* you can set **PPK Version 2** by default for **PuTTYgen** selecting in the app menu:

> Key->Parameters for saving key files... ->PPK file version: 2

[image: PuTTYgen: Private Key File Parameters]

Comment: I tried to load it in PuTTYgen, but it also says "too new"

Comment: @Black You need to use the latest version of PuTTYgen. What makes sense only, if you are stuck with old version of PuTTY on some system, where you need to use the new key. You can download the new version of PuTTYgen on another system, convert the key there, and copy it to the system with the old PuTTY. If you are free to use newest software directly, then go for latest version of PuTTY, and you won't have to convert anything. Note that the OP created/converted the key with latest PuTTYgen, but is trying to use it with old PuTTY. See [my answer](https://superuser.com/q/1647896/213663#1647897).

Answer (score 7):

You have probably used a newer version of PuTTYgen than the version of PuTTY.

There's [new PPK format since PuTTY 0.75](https://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/%7Esgtatham/putty/wishlist/ppk3.html) (released 2021-05-09). So I guess you have used PuTTYgen 0.75 (or newer) to convert your key. But you are trying to use it in an older version of PuTTY.

---

If you are stuck with old version of PuTTU, the new PuTTYgen can generate even the old format: Go to *Key > Parameters for saving key files > PPK file version*.

Answer (score 3):

I've put newer version of `puttygen.exe` and `pageant.exe` in `TortoiseGit\bin` folder and it works

Comment: By the time I got here, I had already setup keys. Replacing the outdated Tgit ones worked well.

Answer (score 2):

Install the Latest version of putty at least 0.75 it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue,

- key generated with PuTTYgen 0.75
- works fine with PuTTY 0.75
- fails with tortoiseGit 2.12.0.0 (format too new)

After reading answer by @martinprikryl

- changed in TortoiseGit->Settings->Network->SSH client to PuTTY's plink - and it works again

Comment: TortoiseGIt bundles outdated putty executables (0.73/0.74). As you have identified this problem you should really open an Issue in the TortoiseGit tracker: https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/-/issues

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to or you can't upgrade due to security policies on your computer, you can download the binary for the newer puttygen.exe, run the binary and load your .ppk file.  Once loaded, go into "Conversions" and select "Export OpenSSH key" and save as a .pem extension.

Next, using the older puttygen, go into "Conversions" and import the .pem file you generated.  Once loaded, "Save private key" to a new .ppk file.

At this point you should be able to use the older putty.exe file to connect to your host with the .ppk file that you saved.

You can verify, assuming you have the .pub file, by saving the file as a new public key and compare the signatures between the 2 .pub files.  The public key signatures, from my experience are the same.

Or as some has already stated, load your .ppk file, go into: Key -> "Parameters for saving keys files ..." and select PPK file version 2 and "Save private key".

Comment: So why would you mess with two versions of PuTTYgen, if you can do it with the new version of PuTTYgen only?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the openssh key to version 2 or 3 with the "puttygen" utility.
Example:

```
puttygen id_rsa --ppk-param version=2 -o id_rsa.ppk
```

to convert the openssh id_rsa identity file to a version 2 ppk file. Version 3 is currently the newest version of the ppk format at the time of this answer.

You can install puttygen natively on Linux, using a Homebrew or MacPort port on macOS(what I did), or on Windows, use the puttygen docker container at https://hub.docker.com/r/zinuzoid/puttygen. The Mac and Linux syntax's are identical.

The Windows(docker) example syntax looks like this:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd):/app zinuzoid/puttygen id_rsa -O private-openssh --ppk-param version=2 -o id_rsa.ppk
```