# Sublime SFTP connection failure

Tags: sftp, sublime-text-3, ide

I am trying to connect a remote server that requires SSH key to connect. I am using Sublime Text 3's SFTP package for development purposes. I can connect through SSH, but sublime sftp fails. I have used standard configuration for this but the Connection timeout error is being shown when I sync both, local and remote. I have included relevant details following.

### `sftp-config.json`

```json
{
    // ... all other settings untouched ...
    "type": "sftp",
    "host": "<ipaddr>",
    "user": "ubuntu",
    "remote_path": "/home/ubuntu/devproject",
    "connect_timeout": 500,
    "ssh_key_file": "C:/Users/Dev-Laptop-008/Documents/MobaXterm/home/.keys/devkey.pem"
    // ... all other settings untouched ...
}
```

### Sublime console error

```
Connecting to SFTP server "ipaddr" as "ubuntu" ..... failure (Connection timeout)
```

### Remote server's `auth.log`

```
Jun 30 05:45:00 developers-den sshd[6475]: Connection closed by authenticating user ubuntu <ipaddr> port 63382 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved the issue by turning on the `sftp` logs (go to `Preferences: SFTP Settings` in Sublime).  My logs included `Unable to load key file "<filename>.ppk" (PuTTY key format too new)`.  Found that issue answered in [this StackExchange question](https://superuser.com/questions/1647896/putty-key-format-too-new-when-using-ppk-file-for-putty-ssh-key-authentication).

Summarizing, create a new `.ppk` file based on an existing `.pem` file using **PuTTYgen** after changing the following setting:

**Key -> Parameters for saving key files... -> PPK file version: 2**

Final `sftp` config:

```
{
    "type": "sftp",
    "host": "<ip address>",
    "user": "<username>",
    "remote_path": "<server path>",
    "connect_timeout": 30,
    "ssh_key_file": "<filename for ppk file>.ppk"
}
```