# couldn't load private key (putty key format to new)

Tags: putty, openssh

received PPK file from our business partner

our B2B system can only accept OpenSSH format

when I try to convert PPK to Open SSH using PuttGen (we have windows), I get the following error "couldn't load private key (putty key format to new)"

Tried different RSA 1 and 2 still same issue. am I missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["PuTTY key format too new" when using ppk file for PuTTY SSH key authentication](https://superuser.com/questions/1647896/putty-key-format-too-new-when-using-ppk-file-for-putty-ssh-key-authentication#1647897)